Construct a foliation on a simply connected compact manifold with all leaves non-compact
Here's my progress so far in this problem:
There are no codimension-one foliations on even dimensional spheres (here's why). Also, by Novikov's theorem any codimension-one foliation on a simply connected 3-manifold must have a compact leaf.
This leaves us with spheres of odd dimension greater than 3, or foliations that are not codimension-one.
However, I still struggle to construct the required foliation.

Do you have a question?

How to construct a foliation on a simply connected compact manifold with all leaves non-compact?

Did you understand the answer?

Yes! Thank you very much!

In 1950s Seifert conjectured that every nonsingular $C^1$ vector field on $S^3$ has a periodic trajectory. This conjecture was disproved in
Kuperberg, Krystyna, A smooth counterexample to the Seifert conjecture, Ann. Math. (2) 140, No. 3, 723-732 (1994). ZBL0856.57024.
This gives a 1-dimensional smooth foliation of the 3-dimensional sphere without compact leaves. Existence of similar 1-dimensional foliations of $S^{2n+1}, n\ge 2$, was known earlier. See here for history and further references.
